# Misunderstanding about microservices authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, jwt, gateway

I have three graphql microservices

- gateway  (@mercurius/gateway)
- user-service
- travels service.

**My thoughts for implementation.**

When a client (react-native app) send a request to register a user, the api gateway allows
it to hit user-service  without authentication. Once at the user-service, the user is
created and token is issued and send back to the client. (This phase is okay for me).

The second phase is when the client send a request to travel-service  that need to be authenticated.
The request arrives at the api gateway, **THE API GATEWAY SHOULD VALIDATE THE TOKEN BEFORE
DIRECTING THE REQUEST TO THE CORRESPONDING SERVICE.**

**My Problem**

If the api gateway must validate the token, it means that it will use the same
library that issued token in user-service (jsonwebtoken) and it will check if the user
sending the request belong to the user database which is located at the user service.

If the api gateway uses the user-service database, the separation of concern
of microservices features is broken because the api gateway will use the same library the
user-service uses to issue the token and it will hit the user-service database everytime
a request arrives. (That is my thought)

is it the best practise to implement this ? or there is another best way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON Web token (JWT) has a couple of key parts.  Importantly, it's normally cryptographically signed, so you can usually trust its contents.  Its main content is a set of *claims*, which include an *issuer* (`iss`) for a second check on who issued it, an *expiration* time (`exp`), and the *subject* (`sub`) of the token – for whom it is valid.

A typical approach I've seen here is for only one part of the system to issue an sign tokens; maybe it's your user service here.  This produces a signed token, with a relatively short expiration time, a known issuer value, and a subject that encodes the specific user identity.

The gateway in turn needs to validate the signature, check the expiration time, and check that the issuer string matches.  The trick here is that these are all very typical JWT operations.  You cite the [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) Node library; these are essentially the options to `jwt.verify()`.  A typical way to retrieve the public key is using the JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) format, and the jsonwebtoken includes a short example of using [jwks-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa) to retrieve that.  Copying their example exactly:

```js
// Verify using getKey callback
// Example uses https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa as a way to fetch the keys.
var jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');
var client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri: 'https://sandrino.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
});
function getKey(header, callback){
  client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
    var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
    callback(null, signingKey);
  });
}

jwt.verify(token, getKey, options, function(err, decoded) {
  console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
});
```

The gateway does *not* need to separately validate the `sub` claim.  It knows the user service has produced the token (with a valid signature) fairly recently, so the user ID is probably valid, unless the user has been deactivated in between them last logging in and the token expiring.

Comment: Hi david. Thanks for your response. This make sense for me now.But when using jwt.verify at the gateway service, I must use the same secret key I use in user-service to sign token. That is it ?.

Comment: You do need to use the same key.  I'd recommend using RSA key signing, so the gateway service can only have access to the public key and can't forge tokens itself.  The JWKS setup at the end of the answer gives you a way to retrieve the key at run time.

Comment: Thanks. I will now start to learn RSA signing. Please can you have a link of some tutorial which implement this with nodejs app?